# Making a map bigger on tap - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

If I were wanting to make a map on my app bigger on touch, how would I do that? Would I use core animation? Example, I want to change my map from 50px height to 70px height on touch.

Thanks :D

Comment: Did you mean scaling your view or making your frame bigger as the scale is constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know when a user is touching the MKMapView and in the method that the user touched the map you do that:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        CGRect rect = myMapView.frame;
        rect.size = CGSizeMake(50, 70);//Set to Bigger Size
        myMapView.frame = rect;
    }];
```

And when the user leaves the touch from map:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        CGRect rect = myMapView.frame;
        rect.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50);//Set to Original Size
        myMapView.frame = rect;
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the resize animated then yes you can use core animation. However if you just want to resize, you can just redraw the map view by doing the following:

```
 CGRect oldFrame = yourMapView.frame;
 oldFrame.size.height = oldFrame.size.height + 20; //aka 50+20 = 70
 yourMapView.frame = oldFrame;
```